# How to store ST monad thing?

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to handle/store random generator(`Gen (ST {..}`) outside of `ST` monad, but I couldn't find how to do.

## Background

I'm under working for some simulation which uses random heavily.
With profiling, I knew that make random numbers takes more than 50% of process time.

To make random number, I use [mwc-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random) and [SFMT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sfmt).
Because of speed issue, I mainly use `SFMT`.
However, comeparing with `SFMT`, `mwc-random` have richer interfaces that I need(like `normal`, `bernoulli`, ..).

After benchmark and read codes, I understand that `mwc-random` is not too slow than `SFMT` when it is used on `ST` monad.
(`SFMT` on `IO` < `MWC` on `ST` << `MWC` on `IO` < `SFMT` on `ST`)
So, I want to make and handle `MWC` random generator on `ST` monad. 
However, I cannot take this generator out from `ST` monad as same as other `ST` things(e.g. `STRef`).

## Problem

Is there any way to handle/store this random generator outside of `ST` monad **safely**?

I tried to study from many packages/codes with `STRef` or something others, but I couldn't figure it out.

## Example

I use random generator in the simulation like this way.

```
import qualified System.Random.MWC as MWC
import GHC.Prim
import Control.Monad

data World = World { randomGen :: MWC.Gen RealWorld }

initWorld = do gen <- MWC.create
               return $ World gen

something gen = do num <- MWC.uniformR (1,100) gen :: IO Int
                   print num

main = do world <- initWorld
          replicateM_ 100 $ something (randomGen world)
```

But, this code does not works.

```
import qualified System.Random.MWC as MWC
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Primitive
import Control.Monad.ST

data World s = World { randomGen :: MWC.Gen (PrimState (ST s))}

initWorld :: ST s (World s)
initWorld = do gen <- MWC.create
               return $ World gen

something gen = do
    let num :: Int
        num = runST $ do num <- MWC.uniformR (1,100) gen
                         return num
    print num

main = do let world = runST initWorld
          replicateM_ 100 $ something (randomGen world)
```

I want rewrite this code to work with `something`.
Do I need to define/rewrite data structure or do something other?
Is there more smart way?

### Points:

1. I need to handle a random generator (like `Gen (PrimState (ST s))`) to reproduce results.
   So, I do not want to produce ad-hoc random generator.
2. I do not wants to save/restore seed. It has too big overhead.
   (save/restore seed takes x12~15 time more than generate one random number)
   It is slower than using on IO monad, so I do not need to do on `ST` monad.
3. I do not want to use unsafe* functions.

Comment: You can't have 2 and 3 at the same time. `save` and `restore` are safe because they copy the underlying vector. Without copying nothing would prevent mutating a supposedly immutable value. Couldn't you just avoid saving and restoring by doing all (or most) of the work in a single ST scope or inside IO?

Comment: Alternatively, this might be a case where `unsafeInterleaveST` is a good choice for "purifying" incremental operations.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to manipulate the generator outside of the ST monad. Because of the type of `runST`, trying to use things which live "inside" the state thread "outside" of it is non-nonsensical. Imagine you had a function of the following type (which is the function you are trying to write):

```
something :: MWC.Gen s -> Int
something gen = runST ...
```

In order to generate random numbers, some stateful computations must be done with the data inside of the `Gen`. At which point will those computations be done? How many times will they be done, if at all? Most importantly - how can `something` be generating random numbers - it is a pure function, after all, so it must return the same value for the same input.

Instead, you should thread the state along, and call `runST` at the end:

```
something :: MWC.Gen s -> ST s Int 
something = MWC.uniformR (1,100) 

main = mapM_ print $ runST $ do 
  w0 <- initWorld 
  replicateM 100 (something $ randomGen w0)
```